# How can I view supported schemes for an app?

Tags: android

I'm trying to open an app from my app.

Is there a way to find out what schemes that specific app supports, so I can open it? (e.g. for opening the Facebook app, you go `fb://`, for opening Phillips Hue app, it's `hue2://`, but for random app `x` I dont know).

Comment: Other than their documentation I don't think there is a way to know the schema for an app.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 right sir, this may helps you sir https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki I'm sorry Ashvin but I mean.. did you even read my request?

Comment: If an app support public custom schemes for sure it's described in their documentation. Otherwise there is no way to know it (and even if you find the string probably it won't work).

Answer (score 0):

Steps to launch new activity as follows:

1.Get intent for package

2.If intent is null redirect user to playstore

3.If intent is not null open activity

```
    public void launchNewActivity(Context context, String packageName) {
    Intent intent = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE) {
        intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    }
    if (intent == null) {
        try {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName));
            context.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + packageName)));
        }
    } else {
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

just find that application's package.
you can find packages via this [page](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28767/view-apps-full-package-name)